# Swift - Calculating Percentage of Circle Filled

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I am using a framework to display a progress circle with animations. However, I am having some trouble displaying a percentage label in the center of it with the correct percentage. No matter what I try, it says 0%.[image]

Here is the code that calculates the percentage:

```
    var circleAngle = progress.angle
    var decimal = circleAngle/360
    var percent = decimal*100
    percentageLabel.text = String(percent) + "%"
```

progress is the variable referring to the circle view itself, and it has an angle property that returns the circle's angle. To debug, I ran some print statements, and I found that when I printed `decimal`, the value was 0. Any ideas on a fix?

Comment: `let percent = circleAngle * 100 / 360`.  Integer arithmetic makes `circleAngle / 360` be `0`, so multiplying by `100` before dividing by `360` avoids this problem.

Comment: You might even want to add `180` for rounding purposes:  `let percent = (circleAngle * 100 + 180) / 360`.

Comment: @vacawama Thank you! This solved my issue!

Comment: I would recommend giving the circle view a `progress` property (0 to 1) rather than an `angle` property.

Comment: Actual solutions should be posted as answers; *thank you*s should be indicated by accepting the answer.